# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-default-theme596-104' for key in CE

Tags: database, magento

I have been trying to create static block in magento and when saving this block got the following error.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-default-theme596-104' for key UNQ_CORE_LAYOUT_LINK_STORE_ID_PACKAGE_THEME_LAYOUT_UPDATE_ID'

I don't know why this is happening. Please help me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique key constraint in your database table which saves a unique combination of layout, link, store id, packet theme update id.

You are saving this entry again ..

```
 5-default-theme596-104
```

2 ways to solve this issue.

```
1) Remove the entry which has this combination and try again
2) Change the values and try again
```